# Is there a verb that describes the agreement of something by people who disagreed originally, and then changed their mind maybe unwillingly?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a verb that describes the agreement on something by people who disagreed originally, and then changed their mind maybe unwillingly?
For example, when some Republican politicians changed their votes for electing McCarthy as the House speaker, under pressures from their party.

Can "fold" be used for that purpose?

I see "fold" can mean [to concede defeat by withdrawing (one's cards) from play (as in poker) or to bring to an end](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fold). But does that imply "unwillingly"?

How about "get in the line"?

Thanks.

Comment: *Is there a verb that describes people ...* Are you sure you are looking for a verb, not an adjective?  Or is your question title something of a shorthand for *Is there a verb describing the actions of people ...*?

Comment: https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/change%20one%27s%20mind

Comment: Does *renege* or *renounce* fit your context? *About face*?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark see my edit. thanks. I was wondering if "fold" can mean the action?

Comment: "Flip-flop" is commonly used and will be the basis of my answer when this is unlocked.

Comment: "To ensure that your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word.  INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used."

Answer (score 1):

I believe the verb is coerced. Unwillingly changing your mind to avoid conflict seems to imply that verb. If the change in votes to elect McCarthy as House Speaker is cited, then less coercion and more concessions to gain votes, from what news I've seen on the subject.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks. can "fold" mean the behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Cave, or cave in.

[MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cave) has

> intransitive verb
>
> 1: to fall in or down especially from being undermined —usually used with in
> 2: to cease to resist : SUBMIT —usually used with in

[Macmillan](https://macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/cave_2) has

> cave or cave in  to suddenly stop opposing something, especially because people
> have persuaded you
> I finally caved and bought a new TV.
> cave to: He caved to pressure and voted in favor of the bill.

Answer (score 1):

"To be pressed," the passive of "to press," can have this meaning. In this case:

> Some Republican politicians **were pressed to change** their votes for electing McCarthy as the House speaker.

Alternatively:

> Some Republican politicians **were pressed into changing** their votes for electing McCarthy as the House speaker.

Per [the Macmillan dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/press_2), both the "to" and "into" forms are correct (see sense 3), with the meaning (in the active voice) of "to try in a determined way to make someone do something."

Answer (score 1):

*Oxford Learner's Dictionary* has this verb:
**begrudge**

> to feel unhappy about having to do, pay or give something

*I begrudge every second I spent trying to help him.*

*They begrudge paying so much money for a second-rate service.*

There is also **concede**. Per *Merriam-Webster*, the verb means:

> 1)to acknowledge grudgingly or hesitantly

*conceded that it might be a good idea*

> 2)to relinquish grudgingly or hesitantly

*concede power*

Comment: Thanks. What meaning can "fold" have?